# Dynamically initialized httpmodule not firing for all requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule

If I add my HttpModule using the following method it fires for the page request only and not for any static image requests.

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyHttpModule), "Start")]


public class MyHttpModule : 
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(MyHttpModule));
    }
}
```

If I register it normally within the `modules` section within `system.webServer`in the web.config the HttpModule works correctly and handles all requests.

The event handler registered in the HttpModule is the `PostAuthorizeRequest`event handler

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have RAMMFAR enabled? [ref: runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx)

Comment: You should put that as an answer. Didn't think to check for that since I didn't need it for the manually added modules. Any idea why?